# Loop through fields from 'single'

Tags: entries, structure, singles

I have a structure for different categories like salad, soup, main course and so on. Basically they share the same fields - but I want to be able to have dynamic singles based on those structures. For example I have a MainMenu-Single where I than can select entries from salads, soups, main courses and so on.

But is there a way to loop through all the fields in that single?

I tried:

```
{% for category in craft.entries.section('foodMenuCategories') %}
    {% if entry.{category} is defined %} 
       ...
```

Sadly that doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure I am understanding the question so I don't want to answer outright, but you shouldn't have curly brackets within your twig. So `{% if entry.category is defined %}`

Comment: thats exacly my problem I have like ten different categories but they need exactly the same snippet and I want to automate the `{% if entry.soup is defined %}` `{% if entry.salad is defined %}` `{% if entry.mainCourse is defined %}` and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a few ways you can do this with twig.

You should be able to check whether the category slug exists as an attribute on the entry object:

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('foodMenuCategories') %}
    {% if category.slug in entry.getAttributes|keys %} 
        ...
```

Or by using the category slug in an array accessor:

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('foodMenuCategories') %}
    {% if entry[category.slug] is defined %}
       ...
```

Or whether the getAttribute() method on the entry model returns anything truthy for that handle:

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('foodMenuCategories') %}
    {% if entry.getAttribute(category.slug) %} 
        ...
```

It's also important, that the slug is the same in every language!

Comment: the .handle is only for categoryGroups so I have to use something different - but the idea is perfect